# CSV file read, file not found exception

Tags: java, spring-mvc, opencsv

I am working on module, which accepts the csv file , upload it inside to `"C:/projectUpload/Upload"`.

Second I have method `parseCSVWithHeader(Class <T> class, String fileName)`, which will read the content of file and then return the java object of the same.

Now I am bit confused here, i have some questions regarding entire file upload and read architecture. I am getting the NullPoiterException as `new FIleReader(fileName)` didn't found any file.

1. I debugged and found only the filename is passed to FileReader (i,e new.csv). Does FileReader expect the entire path of file in String. If yes, then which path

   Original random upload path or the path which we decide to store the files on it?
2. Is it necessary to upload the input the file by user in some other destination?

CONTROLLER CODE:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void saveData(@ModelAttribute("fileInfo") UploadFileInfo fileInfo, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, MyExceptionHandler {

        String filePath = fileUploadUtility.uploadFile(fileInfo.getUploadDocument().getFile().getBytes(), UploadPathEnum.SignedPDF, "ACR_" + fileInfo.getTableId() + "_" + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".csv");


        List<UserInfo> info = new ArrayList<>();
        info = readerUtil.parseCSVWithHeader(UserInfo.class,fileInfo.getUploadDocument().getFile().getName());
        for(UserInfo user:info)
        {
            System.out.println("user id"+ user.getUserId());  
            System.out.println("user id"+ user.getFirstName());
            System.out.println("user id"+ user.getLastName()); 
        }

//        System.out.println("file path is:" + filePath);
    }
```

CSVReaderUtil

```
public class CSVReaderUtil {

//    public CSVReaderUtil(FileReader fileReader, char par) {
//    }

    public static <T> List<T> parseCSVWithHeader(Class<T> cls, String fileName)
            throws IOException {
        CSVReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName), ',');
            MappingStrategy<T> beanStrategy = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<>();
            beanStrategy.setType(cls);

            CsvToBean<T> csvToBean = new CsvToBean<>();
            List<T> emps = csvToBean.parse(beanStrategy, reader);
            System.out.println(emps);
            return emps;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Am I doing the stuff in right direction or not?

Comment: Try `getFile().getAbsolutePath()` instead of `getName`.

Comment: ohkk then which path will it consider, original path or the virtual directory path where we keep the uploaded files

Comment: getAbsolutePath() is not working

Comment: Try `info = readerUtil.parseCSVWithHeader(UserInfo.class, filePath)` and see how that goes.

Comment: Actually I figured it out that, thanks for the suggestions, What I did i just picked the path of file uploaded and read it.Can you please clarify my all the questions I posted